# Could not find dependencies for aspectj-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspect

I have a problem with CTW aspects using aspectj-maven-plugin. I get the following error (execution entry is being highlighted):

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.5:compile failed: Plugin 
     org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact 
     com.sun:tools:jar:1.7.0_21 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre7/../lib/tools.jar (org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-
     plugin:1.5:compile:default:compile)
    - Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.5:test-compile failed: Plugin 
     org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact 
     com.sun:tools:jar:1.7.0_21 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre7/../lib/tools.jar (org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-
     plugin:1.5:test-compile:default:test-compile)
```

On the configuration:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Aspect.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks like as if this plugin was unable to find jdk? But why?

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `JAVA_HOME` set properly? Please check that. It worked perfectly for me. So I think you should add below mentioned plugin and try:

```
<plugin>      
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Run `mvn compile` after that.

Comment: This plugin is also included in the build section. The variable is also set.

Comment: Run mvn with -X flag. Lets see if something is getting surfaced.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the JAVA_HOME env variable. This happened to me when JAVA_HOME is pointed to JRE folder rather than jdk folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please elaborate a bit. Can you provide a code example, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running with java 11, seems like it is only compatible with java 8.

Looking into the project, [aspectj-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin/pull/45/commits) it looks like the update was committed but never actually merged.